# PHP extensions can't find library files

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I get an error telling me that laravel could not find the PDO SQlite driver:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;) 
...
PDOException: could not find driver
/home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
/home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46
/home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SQLiteConnector.php:25
```

so I looked into it, and found that there is no pdo_sqlite.so in my php extensions folder (I'm using php7.3). I tried installing it (apt does not have a php7.3-sqlite or -sqlite3 package), but to no avail. I installed older versions of the sqlite or sqlite3 package but it did not add it. I also have php7.1 and 7.2 installed, and I see there is a pdo_sqlite.so lib in the 7.2 extension folder, but copying it over does not work either as it gets a compile error.

Also, when I enable the pdo_sqlite.so or sqlite3.so extensions, it says it can't find them (obviously as they are not in my extension directory)

How can I either manually install the php libraries or find it via a package manager?

### EDIT:

Here is my Ubuntu version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Both 'apt search' and 'dpkg-query -l' are unsuccessful in findind php7.3-sqlite3

```
→ dpkg-query -l php7.3-sqlite3
dpkg-query: no packages found matching php7.3-sqlite3
```

and

```
→ sudo apt search php7.3-sqlite3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Comment: According to https://packages.debian.org/buster/php7.3-sqlite3, this package exists and can be installed. If this does not work, you should share more details about your system - which Debian / Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Can you show the actual connection code.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie comment, but how do I show that to you? I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say the connection code.

Comment: Have you installed and enabled pdo extension for sqlite?